# Google Maps V2 'the application has stopped unexpectedly' on android SDK v9

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am using my boss's phone to test an app we have developed on iOS and moving over to android.

I have followed [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/) tutorial which when running on the phone gives the error mentioned in the title. I have read that SDKs below 10 do not support maps is that right? Pretty unsure what to do from here. Code:

I have 3 tabs which I load in as fragments, and the fragment in question is:

Note: All imports are correct

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_layout, container, false);

        return V;
    }
}
```

In the view xml file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    map:cameraTilt="45"
    map:cameraZoom="14"
    />
```

Everything is in the manifest that should be. When I remove the  it runs fine. Is there a fix for this sort of thing?

Edit:

Logcat error:

```
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at co.uk.dwdks.kendalmintfest.KendalInfoFragment.onCreateView(KendalInfoFragment.java:16)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     ... 18 more
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/co.uk.dwdks.kendalmintfest-2.apk]
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
06-28 11:25:51.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: This error messages says nothing. Please add the stack trace from your logcat...

Comment: Hi @WarrenFaith I have updated my question with the logcat, that is the only thing showing from this build and its in green

Comment: this can't be your logcat...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I click the play button > then it launches but displays the error. At this point there is no message in the logcat, when I then click dismiss in the app that line shows in the logcat - the only errors that show up in the logcat is when i use the fragment inside of a linear layout

Comment: @WarrenFaith actually see updated answer - logcat is there, sorry about the confusion!

Comment: looks like there is an issue with your build path as he can't find the MapFragment class...

Comment: @WarrenFaith thanks for helping with that - is there a good way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to implement the SupportFragment and the fragment class needs to be: class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! That has removed the error, it says "This app wont run without Google Play Services" now, am I safe to download this?

Comment: If you get a new exception like: NoClassDefFound in R$stylable than you need to add the map programmaticaly :-)

Comment: Have you done this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Inside of the <application> tag I have: `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDaOjws1NXBg_V6on7Jjby-pRYrzqz8DDM" />` but there seems to be an issue as it is erroring in logcat saying:  `06-28 11:41:20.520: E/Google Maps Android API(3664): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).`

Comment: is the key created with your debug.keystore? alias: android and password: android?

Comment: I created the key on google api website for android, I have never used an alias and password in the process though? So possible I was doing the wrong thing

Comment: is it an old key? or do you created a google console project? https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/ also check the permission. maybe you forgot <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I had a typo in the internet! Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: no problem :) i had also to much fails while implementing the api v2. I was not able to add the MapFragment via xml. it is just working when i add the fragment programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maps work (afair) starting form API8. But you need to link your app with `google-play-servces_lib`, which most likely is not done in your case. Also ensure you got all permissions set in Manifest. Finally, check the official docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/